# Por que no me aparecen los mensajes de toastr?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Espero que puedan ayudarme, estoy usando laravel 5.8 y no me aparecen los mensajes de toastr
comenzaré enseñando parte de mi codigo con webpack:

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/js/toastr.js',
    'resources/js/vue.js',
    'resources/js/axios.js',
    'resources/js/app.js',
    ], 'public/js/app.js').
styles([
    'resources/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'resources/css/toastr.css',
    'resources/css/app.css',
    ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

luego mi public app.js:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego mi layouts.app:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego mi archivo blade:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de último el código de controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aparece algún error? Algo en la consola del explorador? Publicá el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Que error te sale en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Hola, por favor trata de postear el código como texto y no como imagen. Es mucho más fácil para depurar y poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: A simple vista se ve bien. Lo que yo haría es probar sin el session. Que error te sale en la consola?

Comment: Hay varios errores que me aparecen al inicio pero son Vue warn, pero ninguno relacionado al toastr.

Comment: He quitado la parte de la session y ahora me aparece "Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined"

Comment: Cuando pruebo toastr en un botón con onClick funciona muy bien, pero no puedo utlizarlo en el controlador.